# Let C++ deduce location of the class/namespace a parameter is defined in

Tags: c++, c++11

This code compiles without any warnings or errors, and is executable.

```
template<class T>
struct testclass
{
    template<int I>
    class inner {};
    template<int I>
    void f(inner<I> ) {}
};

int main()
{
    testclass<bool> test;
    test.f(testclass<bool>::inner<3>()); // l. 13
    return 0;
}
```

Now, what I'd like to do is to omit the `testclass::` in line 13:

```
test.f(inner<3>());
```

It does not work. Is there anything that I can add in `testclass`' definition, so that my code works?

C++11 is allowed.

Comment: You could write `decltype(test)::inner<3>`. You could also supply the parameter of the function as a template parameter, `test.f<3>()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, boilerplate.

Index boilerplate:

```
template<unsigned... Is> struct indexes {typedef indexes<Is...> type;};
template<unsigned Max, unsigned... Is> struct make_indexes:make_indexes<Max-1, Max-1, Is...> {};
template<unsigned... Is> struct make_indexes<0, Is...>:indexes<Is...> {};
```

A helper class to allow proxy construction without naming the enclosing class:

```
template<int I, typename... Args>
struct inner_helper {
  std::tuple<Args...> args;
  template<typename T, unsigned... Is>
  T construct(indexes<Is...>) && {
    return { std::forward<Args>(std::get<Is>(args))... };
  }
  template<typename T>
  T construct() && {
    return std::move(*this).template construct<T>( make_indexes<sizeof...(Args)>() );
  }
};
```

A helper function to give you the syntax you want.  Note that `inner<3>` is now a function call rather than creating an object outside of the enclosing class scope:

```
template<int I, typename... Args>
inner_helper<I, Args...> inner( Args&&... args ) {
  return {std::forward<Args>(args)...};
}
```

We augment `testclass` with two overloads.  One takes an `inner_helper<int, Args...>` and constructs an `inner<int>` using the `Args...`, the other takes `inner<int>`:

```
template<class T>
struct testclass
{
  template<int I>
  class inner {};
  template<int I>
  void f(inner<I> ) {}
  template<int I, typename... Args>
  void f(inner_helper<I, Args...> h) {
    return f( std::move(h).template construct<inner<I>>() );
  }
};
```

And finally, the requested syntax at point of use:

```
int main()
{
  testclass<bool> test;
  test.f(inner<3>()); // l. 13
  return 0;
}
```

this lets you do the syntax you want (`inner<3>()`), supports constructing said `inner<3>` with arbitrary arguments (which get perfect-forwarded), and invokes your actual `f(inner<I>)` method.

It does require that `inner<I>` be move-constructable and implicitly constructable from the arguments to `inner<I>`.

I am assuming that `inner<I>` is a bit more complex than the type you used above.  If it is not more complex, you should consider the SCARY technique of C++ iterators, where the iterator (while an internal type sortof) is actually an external type.

[live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/27620e30da43fd80)

Comment: This exactly answers my question. Thanks!

Comment: @Johannes Oh, the `std::tuple<Args>` could be replaced with `std::tuple<Args&&>`, but that is somewhat dangerous (lifetime extension issues).  So long as the types involves are cheap-to-`move`, `std::tuple<Args>` is a superior option.

Answer (score 7):

In general, there is no global compiler flag that would allow such a deduction, because that would defeat name scoping.

However, you can typedef (or in case of a template - have a type alias) the inner class outside. In your case it would be:

```
template <int I> using inner = testclass::inner<I>;
```

This has to be written in global namespace, not within the `testclass`.

Note that template alias *is* a feature of C++11

Comment: Thanks, but in my case, testclass is a template class, so this is not helpful.

Comment: If testclass itself is a template, why didn't you say so in the question?

Comment: it can be very easly adapted

Comment: template <typename T, int I> using inner = testclass<T>::inner<I>;

Comment: @CygnusX1 Sorry, I did not imagine that someone would post such a simple answer (not meant offensive).

Comment: @LukaRahne This compiles (if I add template and typename keywords), but has the drawback that the compiler still can not deduce `T`. But better than nothing.

Comment: class template can not be deduced. And you needto enter known type, so I dont think that is possible.(AFAIK template deduction goes in way, that function figures out own template type). What you are looking for is that used type si automatically deduced.  But you can do test.f2(test.inner<3>) if that makes simpler.

Comment: @LukaRahne did you say "can not"?  This is C++.  There is no "can not", there is only "I don't know how ... yet".  :)

Answer (score 2):

You can not omit `testclass::`, since `inner` is inner class of testclass class.

What you can do is changing the signature of the `f` function to make it a bit simpler :

```
struct testclass
{
    template<int I>
    class inner {};

    template<int I>
    void f1() {
        inner<I> obj;
    }
    template<typename T>
    void f2( T&& )
    {
    }
};

int main()
{
    testclass test;
    test.f1<3>();
    test.f2(testclass::inner<3>());
}
```